# Does the integral $\int_{0}^{e}\sqrt{x}\ln{x} \ dx$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Splitting: $$\int_{0}^{e}\sqrt{x}\ln{x} \ dx=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x}\ln{x}\ dx + \int_{1}^{e} \sqrt{x}\ln{x} \ dx.$$

Second integral is clearly convergent since it's defined on $[1,e].$ For the first integral, we see that

$$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x}\ln{x}\ dx\leq\int_{0}^{1} 1\cdot\ln{x}\ dx.$$

This implies that $\sqrt{x}\leq1,$ for $x\in[0,1]$ which is true. Now I know that the second integral is convergent with the value of $-1.$ Thus the original integral is also convergent.

---

Please give me feedback on my reasoning. I know I got the correct answer, but is the motivation for it correct and stringent enough? Say this question gives 3 points in a test, how much would this solution warrant?

Is there any faster way do deduce the convergence?

Comment: Even without the $\sqrt{x}$, the $\ln x$ integral converges at the $0$ end.

Comment: the integral converges

Comment: Well, yes that's what was used in my conclusion.

Comment: $\log x < 0$ on $(0,1)$, so your inequality of integral on $[0,1]$ is wrong. You can fix that by taking absolute value in the integrand.

Comment: @achillehui Please elaborate. I don't understand :/

Comment: Look at user296602's answer.

Comment: You can simply use the change of variable $x = e^y$ that maps the interval $x \in [0,e]$ to $y \in [-\infty , 1]$. The other things are straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no: your logic is *not* valid. You used the inequality

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{x} \ln x \, dx\le \int_0^1 \ln x \, dx$$

to conclude that $\sqrt{x} \le 1$, and then concluded that the outcome is true. This has three serious problems:

- You can't use $\int_0^1 f \, dx \le \int_0^1 g \, dx$ to conclude that $f \le g$ regardless.
- The first inequality is actually false, because $\ln x \le 0$ on this interval.
- You cannot derive to something true, and use that to conclude that the premise was true as well.

Also, your argument for convergence on $[1, e]$ isn't correct. The integrand is defined and **bounded**. Having an integrand be defined everywhere does not guarantee convergence.

---

A correct approach would be to do something like the following: Combine that $\sqrt{x} \in [0, 1]$ for $x \in [0, 1]$, the fact that $|\sqrt{x} \ln x| \le |\ln x|$ for $x \in (0, 1]$, and finally that

$$\int_0^1 |\ln x|\, dx$$

converges.

Comment: I'd all of those are merely failings in _writing down_ the argument correctly. The underlying line of thought does appear to be correct.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Unfortunately, I don't agree - the application of the logic was completely reversed from the proper order. I see many of my own students making the same mistake, of working from a premise to a true conclusion, and concluding the premise had to be true as well. Also, the underlying line of thought has several backwards inequalities, and the conclusion that $\int ... \le -1$ implies convergence. There are some bigger issues here.

Comment: 1) I thought that was the comparison theorem for improper integrals? 2) Yeah, $\ln{x}\leq 0$, then the LHS is "less negative" than the RHS in my inrquality. So the inequality sign should be flipped. 3) I don't understand this third point. Yes, i formulated myself wrong, of course definition has nothing to do with divergence or convergence in this case. I will give your suggestion a try and get back.

Comment: @Parseval 1) The comparison theorem states something like $$0 \le f \le g \text{ and } \int_a^b g \text{ convergent } \implies \int_a^b f \text{ convergent.}$$ You're missing the nonnegativity here. 3) You used the *premise* to conclude something about $\sqrt x$, which you said was true. Perhaps it's just written clearly, but to me it looked like you're trying to use a true *conclusion* to get something about the *premise*. That is logically very invalid. Perhaps I misunderstood what you're writing.

Comment: Ahh yes ofcourse, the functions have to be positive! According to what you suggested I should do instead: What do you mean by combining $\sqrt{x}$ and so on? If it's not too much to ask, would you mind elaborating in an answer? I learn better when I see the full picture and understand all the steps inbetween.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this integral
\begin{align}
&\quad\;\int_0^e\sqrt{x}\ln xdx=\frac{2}{3}\int_0^e\ln x d x^{3/2}=\frac{4}{9}\int_0^e\ln x^{3/2} dx^{3/2}\\
&=\frac{4}{9}\int_0^{e^{3/2}}\ln ydy=\frac{4}{9}\left.y(\ln y-1)\right|_0^{e^{3/2}}=\frac{2}{9}e^{3/2},
\end{align}
which is finite, so it converges.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$\int \sqrt{x}\ln(x)dx=\frac{2}{9} x^{3/2} (3 \log (x)-2)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln(x)=0$$

Comment: Seriously? Can you explain how this answers the request of "Please give me feedback on my reasoning"?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are already some answers that answer your specific question, I would like to show the method I would use to show *convergence* of the integral. Denote $f(x)=\sqrt x\ln x$. First, notice that for any $x\in(0,e]$, $f$ is Riemann-integrable over $[x,e]$, since it is bounded (and even continuous) on all such intervals. Therefore, it is locally Riemann-integrable. Now, for $f$ to be an improper integral, i.e., converge, one has to show tha

$$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0^-}\int_{\alpha}^ef(x)dx$$

converges. Using the main theorem of calculus, this is equal to saying that

$$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0^-}(F(e)-F(\alpha)),$$

where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$. It can be found using partial integration and is given by $F(x)=\frac{2}{9}\sqrt{x^3}(-2+\ln x)+c$, where $c\in\mathbb R$ a constant, which might as well be $0$, since it cancels out anyway. Since $F(e)$ is just a constant, we only have to worry about $F(\alpha)$ in the limit. It can be shown using L'Hopital's rule that this term converges to zero, just notice that in

$$F(\alpha)=-\frac{4}{9}\sqrt{\alpha^3}+\frac{2}{9}\sqrt{\alpha^3}\ln \alpha$$

the first term tends to zero if $\alpha$ tends to zero and

$$\sqrt{\alpha^3}\ln \alpha=\frac{\ln \alpha}{\alpha^{-\frac{3}{2}}},$$

to which L'Hospital can be applied to get

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}\frac{\ln \alpha}{\alpha^{-\frac{3}{2}}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}\frac{\alpha^{-1}}{-\frac{3}{2}\alpha^{-\frac{5}{2}}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}-\frac{2}{3}x^\frac{3}{2}=0.$$

Notice that I have ommited the constant $\frac{2}{9}$, since it has no effect on the *convergence* of the limit. Since the limit is $0$, it can be further omitted. In conclusion is $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0^-}(F(e)-F(\alpha))=F(e)$, thus convergent, which imples that the integral is improperly convergent.

Perhaps this method is somewhat longer, instead of shorter as you asked for, but I hope it will give you better insight on how such problems can be approached alternatively (and somewhat more formally).

Please point out any errors you notice!

Comment: Thanks for this, might probably help others. However we are not allowed to use L'Hopital's rule in my university. Not in single variable calculus at least.